# Is there a way to use a local db with a hosted ASP.NET core web app on Azure?

Tags: c#, sql, azure, asp.net-core, web-hosting

I need a SQL database to interact with an ASP.NET core application, mostly for IdentityServer, however, there will be less than 5 user accounts. Since the database will be very small and limited in usage, I would rather not have to have a dedicated SQL server alongside the web app that is already being hosted.

Is it possible to have a sort of "local" database that runs in the web app?

The database would need to persist through redeploying and restarting the application.

Comment: Why not use something like CosmosDB?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible. You will have to enable the protocol, set up the ports, configure the firewalls etc. essentially to expose the SQL server running on your computer as a endpoint so your ASP.NET app can talk to.

However, that's a lot of work to set up. And will be quite a fair bit of maintenance too. I really do suggest you setup an Azure SQL database (which will cost you as low as 5 dollar/month if I remember correctly), or else, try to find some free tier (I remember AWS has a free tier for SQL database). It will be up in no time and the providers will do the maintenance for you, integration will be seamless too.